# How to do conditional merge Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

I have two different dataframes shown below.

This is the `tel_times` dataframe

[image]

And this is the `maint_comp1` dataframe.

[image]

Now, I have joined these two dataframes using `merge`.

```
maint_tel_comp1 = pd.merge(tel_times, maint_comp1,  how='inner', left_on=['machineID','datetime_tel'], right_on = ['machineID','datetime_maint'])
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
maint_tel_comp1 = tel_times.merge(maint_comp1, on='machineID', how='inner')
maint_tel_comp1[maint_tel_comp1['datetime_tel'].gt(maint_tel_comp1['datetime_maint'])]
```

The problem is your merge was also ensuring `datetime_tel == datetime_maint`, hence your condition was returning an empty DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you please upvote the question too?